# How to write a query to get route id based on multiple parameters?

Tags: mysql, sql

I designed this simple model and I am with some difficulties to write the desirable query.

To start with, here's the markdown of the 3 tables that I have:

**SELECT * FROM Routes;**

| Id | Content |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Route 1 |
| 2 | Route 2 |

**SELECT * FROM PointsOfInterest;**

| Id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Oceanário |
| 2 | Mosteiro dos Jerónimos |
| 3 | Torre de Belém |

**SELECT * FROM Routes_PointsOfInterest;**

| RouteId | PointOfInterestId | Order_Position |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 | 1 |

I need to find the RouteId for multiple points of interested in a known order. So, for example, I need to find the route corresponding to the points of interest 1, 2 and 3 in the order 1->2->3. So this one should return RouteId=1. However, for the same points of interest 1, 2 and 3, in the order (3->2->1) the RouteId should be 2.

Basically this means that the route from PoI 1 to PoI 3 is different from the route from PoI 3 to PoI 1.

I designed this tables, so maybe this isn't the best approach to design the tables. If it helps, I can alter all this schema.

Here's the minimum amount of code to reproduce my problem:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0cdee8/1
or
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/v3GZPCHpmdyBRCFGCsr2im/0

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm . . . one method is aggregation and using strings for the match:

```
select rp.routeid
from Routes_PointsOfInterest  rp
where rp.PointOfInterestId in (1, 2, 3)
group by rp.routeid
having group_concat(rp.PointOfInterestId order by rp.position) = '1,2,3';
```

EDIT:  For your question of only including 1,2,3, just remove the `where` clause:

```
select rp.routeid
from Routes_PointsOfInterest  rp
group by rp.routeid
having group_concat(rp.PointOfInterestId order by rp.position) = '1,2,3'
```

Comment: This query looks nice but it fails to retrieve the correct route when there's  routes with  less points in the same positions. For example, your query correctly returns route 1 for the "1,2,3" combination, but if we have the combination "1,2,3,4", the route with this combination will also be returned. Do you know how can we avoid that, so we can retrieve only the correct route? I feel like we should add some count() = number of points we are looking for to the having clause, but I wasn't succeeded doing so. Here's the schema updated with this example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0f94cc/2